# Closed/compact form solution for $\int_{0}^\infty\int_{x_1/z}^\infty \frac{e^{-y_1(z+1)}}{1+z-\frac{x_1}{y_1}}\,dy_1\,dx_1$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to solve this double integral

$$\int\limits_{x_1=0}^{\infty}\int\limits_{y_1=\frac{x_1}{z}}^{\infty}
  \frac{e^{-y_1(z+1)}}{1+z-\frac{x_1}{y_1}}\,dy_1\,dx_1$$

where $z> 0$. Is there any tricks such that I can evaluate it in a closed/compact form?

I know I have to provide my attempt, which I usually do, but this time I am clueless.

I apprentice any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** for $x_1$ fixed, set $t=\frac{y_1}{x_1}$ in the inner integral. Then, \begin{align*}\int_{x_1=0}^{\infty}\int_{y_1=\frac{x_1}{z}}^{\infty}
  \frac{e^{-y_1(z+1)}}{1+z-\frac{x_1}{y_1}}\,dy_1\,dx_1&=\int_{x_1=0}^{\infty}\int_{t=\frac{1}{z}}^{\infty}
  \frac{x_1e^{-tx_1(z+1)}}{1+z-\frac{1}{t}}\,dt\,dx_1\\
&=\int_{t=\frac{1}{z}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+z-\frac{1}{t}}\int_{x_1=0}^{\infty}x_1e^{-tx_1(z+1)}\,dx_1\,dt\\
&=\int_{t=\frac{1}{z}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+z-\frac{1}{t}}\frac{1}{t^2(z+1)^2}\,dt.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you. Now the final integral will be solved using partial fraction, right? I tried this approach, and it gives $\infty$!!

Comment: I don't see how you get $\infty$. You have that $t\geq\frac{1}{z}$, so $0<\frac{1}{1+z-\frac{1}{t}}\leq 1$, and the integral $\int_{1/z}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^2}\,dt$ converges.

Comment: I re-wrote the integral as $$\frac{1}{(z+1)^2}\int_{1/z}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t(t(z+1)-1)}dt = \frac{1}{(z+1)^2}\left[-\int_{1/z}^{\infty}\frac{1\,dt}{t}+\int_{1/z}^{\infty}\frac{z+1}{t(z+1)-1}\,dt\right]$$. The integral of $1/t$ is $\ln(t)$, and $\ln$ at $\infty$ is $\infty$. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Both those integrals are divergent, so you should not break them like this. Write instead \begin{align*}\frac{1}{(z+1)^2}\int_{1/z}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+z)t^2-t}\,dt&=\frac{1}{(z+1)^2}\int_{1/z}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{t}+\frac{z+1}{t(z+1)-1}\right)\,dt\\&=\frac{1}{(z+1)^2}\left[-\ln t+\ln\left(t-\frac{1}{z+1}\right)\right]_{1/z}^{\infty}\\
&=\frac{1}{(z+1)^2}\left[\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{t(z+1)}\right)\right]_{1/z}^{\infty}\\
&=\frac{\ln(z+1)}{(z+1)^2}.\end{align*}

Comment: I see the trick. That was elegant. Thanks again.